# Django User Logout Fails to Redirect Homepage

Tags: python, django, redirect

After log out user in my django web app, the redirected homepage still displays the "Log Out" button instead of the "Sign in with Facebook". In the following code, I follow the django documentation to logout the user and redirect the page to homepage which is the base.html. It seems that my web app still has user.is_authenticated as True after log out? What am I missing?

I cannot find any useful hint online. Any comment is much appreciated.

Here is part of my template html

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                      <a id="logout" href="/accounts/logout" class="btn btn-success">Logout</a>
                    {% else %} 
                      <a id="facebook_login" href="/accounts/facebook/login" class="btn btn-success">Sign in with Facebook</a>
                    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Here is my urls.py

```
url(r'^$', 'homepage.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'homepage.views.logout', name='logout'),
```

Here is my homepage/views.py

```
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, "base.html", {})

# ensure only logged in users can access the view.
@login_required
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    # Take the user back to the homepage.
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things here:

1. You need to reorder the URLs

from:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'homepage.views.logout', name='logout'),
```

to

```
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'homepage.views.logout', name='logout'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

This way, your logout takes precedence over the allauth's logout URL pattern

2. You should be aliasing the imported `logout`, or rename your `logout` to something different.

Example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
```

and then

```
def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)

    ....
```

Comment: Hi Karthikr, I marked it as accepted. Thank you for the quick and effective answer. Would you recommend some open source django web apps for me to study? I searched online but answers are diverse. This question is asked multiple times here on stackoverflow. So I put it as a comment and I am sure you have valuable answer in mind.

Comment: I have found djangogirls tutorials to be pretty good (https://github.com/djangogirls/tutorial). Also, I would recommend checking out a skeleton project - such as this: https://github.com/rdegges/django-skel and trying to write code on top of it.. That way, it gives you a hang of framework, etc..

Comment: wonderful! Any books you recommend? the book "Tango with Django"? or "Django with Examples"?

Comment: Totally upto you. I personally am not a kind of person who would read books, etc..